# UIBezierPath simple rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I just want to draw a simple rectangle to a view using the following function:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    if (self.drawTextBouble) {
        [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
        UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(40, 0, 230, 120) cornerRadius:12.0];
        [aPath fill];
    }
}
```

The code above fills the view with plain black background, outside the rectangle is not transparent. How can I fix this?

Edit:

The solution below is working, but this is working also:

```
[self setOpaque:NO];
```

Comment: This is a better example of a question than I thought it was going to be. There's existing, erroneous code, explanation of the problem and the desired outcome. It's a shame I don't know the answer!

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem with your code, but perhaps you should not call `[super drawRect:rect]`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074281/subclassed-uiview-shows-black-background-if-drawrect-is-overridden.

Comment: thank you for the comments:), I tried but behaves the same.

Comment: @flatronka: Are you sure that the view's background color is set to transparent ("clearColor") ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You drawing code is OK. If you want the custom drawn view to have transparent background, you just need to set

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

in view's `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`

Edit: Just a little note regarding calling `[super drawRect:rect]`. `UIView` docs says:

> If you subclass `UIView` directly, your implementation of this method does not need to call super. However, if you are subclassing a different view class, you should call super at some point in your implementation.

Comment: thank you this is working, I found an alternative solution which is working also.